# Prove that in every metric space $X$ , the set $ X\setminus \{x\} $ is an open set in X.

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove that in every metric space $X$ , the set $X$ \ {x}   is an open set in X.

I started by suposing the opposite that  $X$ \ {x}  is a closed set in $ X $  which means tht the complement  $ ( X $ \ {x})$ ^c$  = {x}   is an open set , which is a contradiction. Im not sure if i have the right contradiction . Can anyone help me ? Thank you !

Comment: The opposite of "$X \setminus \{x\}$ is open" is **not** "$X \setminus \{x\}$ is closed". A set can be neither open nor closed. For example, the half-open interval $(a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is neither open nor closed in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Bungo is right. Let's imagine for example the set X={a,b} with the topology: ${{a,b},a,b, \emptyset }$ it is clear that b and X\{b} are both open and both closed. And they are "opposite".

Hint for solving your problem: all metric spaces are Hausdorff

Comment: Alternatively, if you have available the standard fact that the distance function $d: X \times X \to [0, \infty)$ is continuous, so its restriction to $\{x\} \times X$, but $X \setminus \{x\}$ is just the preimage of the open set $(0, \infty)$ under this restriction.

Answer (score 4):

It’s entirely possible for $\{x\}$ to be an open set. For example, take $X$ to be $\Bbb Z$, the set of integers, with the usual metric. Then for each $n\in\Bbb Z$ we have $\{n\}=\{m\in\Bbb Z:|m-n|<1\}$, the open ball of radius $1$ centred at $n$, which is certainly an open set.

You should instead try to prove directly that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open. To do this, let $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, and try to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\epsilon)\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$. Note that this is the same as saying that $x\notin B(y,\epsilon)$; can you find an $\epsilon$ for which this is true? Note that the choice of $\epsilon$ will depend on $y$.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of "$S$ is open" is **not** "$S$ is closed".  There are sets that are neither closed nor open, and sets that are both.

The real point to consider here is that the set $\{x\}$ is closed.  This will be true in every metric space.  Sometimes, it will also be open.

Comment: The terminology **is** terrible, so we should insist on your first sentence at every opportunity. *Sets aren't doors.*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Comment: @Bungo I knew what it was before I clicked :)

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong (twice).

Firstly, the "opposite" of open is not closed.

Secondly, $\{x\}$ can be open. Consider the metric space $X=\{x\}$.

What you want to do is prove that every point-set is closed. This follows easily from hausdorffness, which is a property of metric spaces. Since point-sets are closed, the complement of closed is open, finite intersection of open sets is open and the whole metric space is open, you have that $X\backslash \{x\}=X \cap \{x\}^c$ is open.

Comment: I prefer "Hausdorffitude" as an adjective

Comment: I believe the correct term is “Hausdorffiosity”.